# Excel 2010: Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, subscript

The error that I am receiving is Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'Turn off any alerts that maybe displayed.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Turn of the screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare the workbook, create it, save it and close it
Dim wk As Workbook
Set wk = Workbooks.Add
wk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Saved File\KPI_Grid.xlsm", FileFormat:=52, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
wk.Close

'Open the workbook again. This will get rid of the 'Compatibilty View' and then activate the orginal workbook
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Saved File\KPI_Grid.xlsm"
Workbooks("KPI Grid V5K1 - macro testing.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Weekly").Activate
'Select all cells and copy them
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
'Activate the workbook and sheet that we are going to paste into.
Workbooks("KPI_Grid.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate   ' ******************ERROR HERE ******************
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
'Activate the previous workbook again.
Workbooks("KPI Grid V5k1 - macro testing.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Monthly").Activate
Cells.Select
Cells.Copy
Workbooks("KPI_Grid.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

I thought this was a relatively simple task.
The aim is to create a new workbook, copy the values of two sheets over and then save and close the new workbook.
Why does this code error?

Comment: I just stumbled across an old post that you had commented about a similar situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815124/run-time-error9-subscript-out-of-range?rq=1 - how do you check titles for a sheet name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`
Press `F9`
Press `F5`
Check the screen - has the workbook "KPI_Grid.xlsm" been activated ?
Does it actually have a sheet called "Sheet1" ?

If Sheet1 is not in the same workbook as the code then this will naturally error - you need to ensure everything is *qualified* like this:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Activate`

Comment: Hi whytheq,
I clicked did the above and it throws a run time error 1004. I ran a quick search around the net and it says that this maybe because my code is in the ThisWorkbook. Could this be the route of my issues? I also tried doing the above against the line above it and it also threw the same error.
Regards,

Comment: @DJenkins - rather than F5 try just stepping through with `F8` - on what line does it first bug?

Comment: ....wait there - if Sheet1 is not in the same workbook as the code then of course it will error!

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Activate

That worked beautifully. I thought that the line before Workbooks("KPI_Grid.xlsm").Activate did this. HMMMM, think its time to buy a VBA book and have a good read rather than piecing things together from around the net! and a big thank you for helping out.